# Installing Nvidia Drivers on 13.04 and Removing Loading Choice Screen on Startup

Tags: installation, nvidia, startup

I am brand new to Ubuntu, after many years with Windows and a dabble with OSX, so please go easy on me. Yesterday, after ruining the pre-installed Windows 8 with the Ubuntu install  I had to install my copy of Windows 7, in which I couldn't get any WIFI, so I then erased Windows 7 with Ubuntu 13.04....

I have a couple of questions please.

1. When I turn on my laptop, I get the Purple screen which lists choices of Ubuntu, and Windows 7 loader, even though Ubuntu erased this on install, and a couple of other choices...How do I completely get rid of that screen, so my Laptop boots straight to Ubuntu, without me having to make a choice?
2. On my laptop I have Nvidia Graphics card 675m.  I tried to install Nvidia drivers via the Software Updater, in 'Additional Drivers', I chose the latest one '313' and '310', both changed the resolution in Ubuntu and make the laptop flash with a crackly black screen on Shutdown and Startup.  When I installed the drivers I also could not find any Nvidia control panel.

   So how do I safely install Nvidia drivers?  I know there is a long winded install using a Virtual console, which I have never used in my life.  Do I have to download the drivers from Nvidia first from their website before doing anything?

Thanks in advance,

D.

Comment: Please don't club multiple question in one thread. Open different thread for each question if they are not related. I am answering the first query. Edit your question to remove second one and recreate another question. It is very difficult to answer all question in one answer. See [FAQ]. For the second issue, in your new question please include result of `lspci`

Answer (score 0):

The windows boot manager resides on a separate small partition (around 100mb). Most probably that partition is not deleted that is why the entry is listed.

There are multiple solution :

1. Most easy one if you are not installing any other OS :

   - Open a terminal, type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - At bottom add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` (this will disable other os search function)
   - Save and close the file.
   - run `sudo update-grub`
2. Change Time for which the menu is shown

   - Open a terminal, type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - Search and Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` value to `0`. It will be `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`
   - Save and close the file.
   - run `sudo update-grub`

**After doing above if you need grub for some cause (like for booting older kernel), press <kbd>shift</kbd> while booting to get GRUB menu**

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do I run sudo update-grub?  Also, do I have to do both these tasks, or one of the two?

Comment: in the same terminal. Any one. First one will do. :)